# Asynchronous loop within an asynchronous loop in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I am working on a web-scraping bot which needs to return all of its information very quickly. My main class `Whole` generates a list of Query objects. Here is my query class:

```
class Query: #each query has search term and thing(s) to check the commonality of.
    def __init__(self, query, terms):
        assert type(query)==str
        self.query = query
        self.terms = terms
        self.response = None

    def visible(self,element):
        if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']:
            return False
        elif re.match(r'<!--.*-->', str(element.encode('utf-8'))):
            return False
        return True

    def processResponse(self, loop):
        self.texts = None
        async def fetch(url, session):
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                return await response.read()

        async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
            # Getter function with semaphore.
            async with sem:
                await fetch(url, session)

        async def run(pages):
            tasks = []
            sem = asyncio.Semaphore(100)

            # Fetch all responses within one Client session,
            # keep connection alive for all requests.
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                for page in pages:
                    task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem,page, session))
                    tasks.append(task)

                responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                self.texts = responses

                # you now have all response bodies in this variable
        pages = list([item['link'] for item in self.response['items']])  #all of the links to search
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(pages))
```

Each "query" has a list of pages to search and a list of words to scan for on those pages. The `Whole` class contains a list of multiple of these `Query` objects. I would like to simultaneously execute all of the necessary requests for all `Query`s and have the responses be returned to each individual Query object for further parsing. I tried to create two event loops, one in `Whole` and the one above in `Query`, but then I realized I can't have more than one event loop. How can I create a function that executes all of the searches of multiple `Query`s asynchronously? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Note: Please ignore the `visible` function. It is simply for parsing once the page data is retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I create a function that executes all of the searches of multiple `Query`s asynchronously?

Change `processResponse` to an `async def` and replace its last line with `await run(pages)`. Then in the `Whole`, await `asyncio.gather(*[q.processResponse() for q in queries])` just like you did in `processResponse`.

Comment: followup: How could I set the `max_workers` in the Whole class? Or use Semaphore or some other class to be sure ALL requests are run in parallel?

Comment: @NameerHirschkind `asyncio.gather` should run all requests in parallel, you shouldn't need to do anything special. Note that a `Semaphore` does the inverse of what you're asking, it serves to *limit* the number of parallel requests that go through it.